Excel SharePoint issue: New Version Available message keeps interrupting work
I am an Excel VBA developer. I have an Excel document which uses a UserForm to accept users' input, and then record results onto a spreadsheet in sequential fashion. I ask users to only use the form to add data, and not to entry data directly onto the sheet (the form processes a lot of things).
However, frequently we see a message at the top of the Excel window, stating "NEW VERSION AVAILABLE. We cannot apply changes made by someone else." This is accompanied by an invitation to reopen the document.
I have looked up this error on Google, and some answers mention that it might be a versioning issue. However, I work in an organisation where everything is tightly controlled: all users have the same version of Excel on their machines: Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise. Excel version 2308, build 16731.20716.
Could it possibly be something to do with the fact that I use a VBA UserForm? I have added the line ThisWorkbook.Save before and after the lines are added - to ensure synchronicity. But still the error occurs.
I thought that SharePoint was supposed to eliminate issues like this. Although I am an experienced Excel user, I have very little experience with SharePoint. Can anyone advise please?

Note that I am unable to upload an image of the error message while at work, as Stackoverflow keeps giving its own error message after I select the file :)

Tried the suggested fix here?  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/refresh-recommended-a-newer-version-of-this-file/8e72069d-fcec-450c-8cd6-4c1b6383d9e1

@TimWilliams - Thank you. I will try that, and let you know if it works. Have you considered posting this as an actual answer, instead of just a comment? Therefore if it does work, I can mark it as solved :)

I don't have any way of testing it, so a comment seemed more appropriate.  If it works then I could post it as an answer.

@TimWilliams Unfortunately, it didn't work. Back to square one... But thank you anyway.
